# Spring data elasticsearch repository with Pageable is retuning only 10000 documents

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have index with 17364 documents in elasticsearch.

```
$curl http://localhost:9200/performance/_count
{"count":17364,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0}}
```

Spring data repository,

```
public interface TestRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Transaction, String> {
}
```

Fetch all documents page by page and print:

```
public void testReport() {

  int page = 0, pageSize = 1000;
  Pageable of = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize);

  Page<Transaction> all = testRepository.findAll(of);
  int numberOfPages = all.getTotalPages();

  log.info("All pages: {},  {}", numberOfPages, all.getTotalElements());
  do {
     log.info("Current page: {}, {}", of.getPageNumber(), of.getPageSize());
     for (Transaction txn : all) {
        log.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(txn));
     }
  } while ((of = of.next()) != null && (transactionRepository.findAll(of)) != null);

}
```

This code is returning only 10000 documents although the index has 17364 documents. Could you please help me to find why this is happening.

- ElasticSearch Version: 7.9
- spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.3.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

A. Since you have only 17364 documents, you could increase the `index.max_result_window` setting in your index to (e.g.) 20000, so that you can paginate till the end:

```
PUT performance/_settings
{
  "index.max_result_window": 20000
}
```

B. If you have a bigger index and/or increasing the `index.max_result_window` limit is not an option for any reason, then you need to leverage the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results). Spring Data ES [supports two ways](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.misc) for doing that.

The first method involves leveraging the `ElasticsearchTemplate.searchForStream()` method which internally uses the Scroll API

```
SearchHitsIterator<Transaction> stream = elasticsearchTemplate.searchForStream(searchQuery, Transaction.class, "performance");
```

The second method is a bit more low-level. You need to modify your repository definition with a method that returns a `Stream`:

```
public interface TestRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Transaction, String> {
    Stream<Transaction> findScrollAll();
}
```

And then implement that method with `ElasticsearchTemplate. searchScrollStart()` and `ElasticsearchTemplate. searchScrollContinue()`

**Addition**:

3rd option:

Just define a method

```
Stream<Searchhit<Transaction>> searchBy()
```

in your `Testrepository`. Or with just the return type `Stream<Transaction>`.

Comment: @PJMeisch thanks for your contribution, but isn't that the same as my second option?